# How to update a particular row using id in redbean php

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have database with table "users"

```
+------+--------------+----------+
|  id  |  username    | password | 
|  22  |  foo         |    foo   |
|  23  |  bar         |    bar   | 
|  24  |  world       |  world   |
```

I wanna update the username where id = 24

How can i do this using redbean without sequel queries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, [`R::load`](http://redbeanphp.com//loading_a_bean) the row into a bean:

```
$user = R::load('users', 24);
```

Then update your data:

```
$user->username = "Bojangles";
```

And finally save the user back to the table:

```
R::store($user);
```

Please be sure to read the manual in the future - an example of how to do this is [on the homepage](http://redbeanphp.com)

Answer (score 0):

But your execute code doing two query instead one.

I think that it is better:

$sQuery = "UPDATE users SET username='Bojangles' WHERE id=24 ";
R::exec( $sQuery );

imho